# Prioritize equations in a nonlinear system

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a nonlinear EQS using the least squares method. I get a result, but unfortunately it is not very accurate. The main problem is that the equations 29 to 32 must be fullfilled, but they are not. Is there a way to maybe prioritize equations in a nonlinear system?

Here is the my code:

```
# Ethanol and 1_Propanol with 3 trays

from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import numpy as np


def equations(x):
    eq1 = x[18] - x[16] * x[19] * x[11] * (x[21] / (x[19] * x[11] * x[13])) ** (2.0 / 3.0)
    eq2 = x[19] - ((732.0 * x[10]) + (747.0 * x[9]))
    eq3 = x[13] - ((1.25E-5 * x[10]) + (1.6E-6 * x[9]))
    eq4 = x[2] - ((((((-6021.54) + (0.055134232180918 * (x[29] - 298.0))) + 2.61275786690816) * x[10])
                   + ((((-6883.827) + (0.058471271259418 * (x[29] - 298.0))) + 2.38446400137128) * x[9])))
    eq5 = x[11] - (((0.055134232180918 * (x[29])) + 2.61275786690816) * x[10] + ((0.058471271259418 * (x[29])) +
                                                                                 2.38446400137128) * x[9])
    eq6 = x[21] - ((((((0.001318 * (x[29])) + 0.16762) * x[10])
                     + (((-0.001075424413 * (x[29])) + 0.155701011727667) * x[9]))))
    eq7 = x[24] - (1.746 * x[22] + 2.76 * x[20])
    eq8 = x[15] - (1.0E-5 * x[22] + 6.5E-6 * x[20])
    eq9 = x[12] - ((((((((-6021.54) + (0.015220202121093 * (x[26] - 298.0))) + 1.60395800121061) + 922.194)
                      * x[22]) + ((((((-6883.827) + (0.01847750929725 * (x[26] - 298.0))) + 1.43843773750579)
                                    + 1067.523)) * x[20]))))
    eq10 = x[6] - ((((((((0.015220202121093 * (x[26])) + 1.60395800121061)
                        * x[22]) + (((0.01847750929725 * (x[26])) + 1.43843773750579)
                                    * x[20]))))))
    eq11 = x[5] - ((((((((5.07392141746E-4 * (x[29])) + 0.015070468544221)
                        * x[22]) + (((4.89248E-4 * (x[29])) + 0.014354384)
                                    * x[20]))))))
    eq12 = x[3] - (1.0 / (10.0 ** (5.24677 - 1598.673 / (x[28] + 46.424))))
    eq13 = x[0] - (1.0 / (10.0 ** (5.31384 - 1690.864 / (x[28] + 51.804))))
    eq14 = x[27] - (x[25] * x[24] * x[6] * ((x[5] / (x[24] * x[6] * x[15])) ** (2.0 / 3.0)))
    eq15 = 0.0 - ((2.0 * 28000.0) - (x[23] * x[2]) + (x[17] * 0.002))
    eq16 = 0.0 - ((0.2 * 30000.0) - (x[14] * x[12]) - (x[17] * 0.002))
    eq17 = 0.0 - ((2.0 * 0.5) - (x[23] * x[10]) + (x[8] * 0.002))
    eq18 = 0.0 - ((2.0 * 0.5) - (x[23] * x[9]) + (x[7] * 0.002))
    eq19 = 0.0 - ((0.2 * 0.6) - (x[14] * x[22]) - (x[8] * 0.002))
    eq20 = 0.0 - ((0.2 * 0.4) - (x[14] * x[20]) - (x[7] * 0.002))
    eq21 = 0.0 - (x[31] - (x[3] * x[4]))
    eq22 = 0.0 - (x[30] - (x[0] * x[1]))
    eq23 = x[17] - (x[18] * (x[28] - x[29]) + (x[8] * (((-6021.54 + (0.055134232180918 * (x[29] - 298.0))) +
                                                        2.61275786690816) + (x[7] * (
            (-6883.827 + (0.058471271259418 * (x[29] - 298.0))) + 2.38446400137128)))))
    eq24 = x[17] - (x[27] * (x[26] - x[28]) + (x[8] * ((((-6021.54 + (0.015220202121093 * (x[26] - 298.0))) +
                                                         1.60395800121061) + 922.194) + (x[7] * (
            ((-6883.827 + (0.01847750929725 * (x[26] - 298.0))) + 1.43843773750579) + 1067.523)))))
    eq25 = x[8] - (x[19] * x[16] * (x[4] - x[10]) + x[10] * (x[8] + x[7]))
    eq26 = x[7] - (x[19] * x[16] * (x[1] - x[9]) + x[9] * (x[8] + x[7]))
    eq27 = x[8] - (x[24] * x[25] * (x[22] - x[31]) + x[22] * (x[8] + x[7]))
    eq28 = x[7] - (x[24] * x[25] * (x[20] - x[30]) + x[20] * (x[8] + x[7]))
    eq29 = 1.0 - (x[10] + x[9])
    eq30 = 1.0 - (x[4] + x[1])
    eq31 = 1.0 - (x[22] + x[20])
    eq32 = 1.0 - (x[31] + x[30])

    return [eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11, eq12, eq13, eq14, eq15, eq16,
            eq17, eq18, eq19, eq20, eq21, eq22, eq23, eq24, eq25, eq26, eq27, eq28, eq29, eq30,
            eq31, eq32]


# Boundaries
# Upper bounds for specific variables
upper_bounds = np.ones(32) * np.inf
upper_bounds[1] = 1
upper_bounds[4] = 1
upper_bounds[9] = 1
upper_bounds[10] = 1
upper_bounds[20] = 1
upper_bounds[22] = 1
upper_bounds[30] = 1
upper_bounds[31] = 1

# Upper bounds for specific variables
bottom_bounds = np.zeros(32)
bottom_bounds[26] = 340
bottom_bounds[28] = 340
bottom_bounds[29] = 340

# Bounds array
bounds = (bottom_bounds, upper_bounds)
# bounds = (0, np.inf)


# Initial values
x0 = np.ones(32)
x0[1] = 0.5
x0[4] = 0.5
x0[9] = 0.5
x0[10] = 0.5
x0[20] = 0.5
x0[22] = 0.5
x0[30] = 0.5
x0[31] = 0.5

x0[26] = 370
x0[28] = 370
x0[29] = 370


# x0 = np.array([1, 1e-4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1e-4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])


# Lösung des Gleichungssystems mit Variablengrenzen
res = least_squares(equations, x0, bounds=bounds, method='trf', ftol=1e-10, xtol=1e-10, gtol=1e-10)

print(res.x)
print('e0_K_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[0]))
print('e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[1]))
print('e0_h_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[2]))
print('e0_K_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[3]))
print('e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[4]))
print('e0_greek_lambda_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[5]))
print('e0_cp_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[6]))
print('e0_f_int_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[7]))
print('e0_f_int_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[8]))
print('e0_x_L_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[9]))
print('e0_x_L_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[10]))
print('e0_cp_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[11]))
print('e0_h_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[12]))
print('e0_D_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[13]))
print('e0_F_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[14]))
print('e0_D_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[15]))
print('e0_greek_beta_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[16]))
print('e0_e_int_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[17]))
print('e0_greek_alpha_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[18]))
print('e0_greek_rho_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[19]))
print('e0_x_V_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[20]))
print('e0_greek_lambda_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[21]))
print('e0_x_V_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[22]))
print('e0_F_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[23]))
print('e0_greek_rho_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[24]))
print('e0_greek_beta_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[25]))
print('e0_T_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[26]))
print('e0_greek_alpha_V_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[27]))
print('e0_T_int_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[28]))
print('e0_T_L_tr1 {0}'.format(res.x[29]))
print('e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[30]))
print('e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[31]))

print('Zusammensetztungen:')

print('e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[31]))
print('e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[30]))

print('e0_x_V_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[22]))
print('e0_x_V_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[20]))

print('e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[4]))
print('e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[1]))

print('e0_x_L_tr1_c1 {0}'.format(res.x[10]))
print('e0_x_L_tr1_c2 {0}'.format(res.x[9]))
```

and the results for `x[31]`, `x[30]`, `x[22]`,... are:

```
Zusammensetztungen:
e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1 0.5189962572539993
e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2 0.24082903753005624
e0_x_V_tr1_c1 2.3066615630447933e-32
e0_x_V_tr1_c2 1.246796204196686e-33
e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1 0.9999999999999999
e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2 0.01258253962013115
e0_x_L_tr1_c1 7.013309435002394e-33
e0_x_L_tr1_c2 3.0913699644636455e-33
```

but `e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1 + e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2` should be 1, but it's not.

Comment: If you want some values to equal 1 why not defining it as a constraint? To answer your question, the discrepancy can be due to the optimizer falling into a local minima (try a different initialization to check this) or total square is smaller at this point than on your constrained subspace.

Comment: Look into Weighted Least Squares.

Comment: Examine equation 23. I believe, despite (or because of?) your dozens upon dozens of superfluous parentheses, that there is a mis-multiplication in there due to a misplaced parenthesis.

Comment: Equation 24 is suspicious for the same structural reason.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your redundant parentheses and reformat your equations so that they can be more easily debugged.

Replace your indexed variables with named variables. I show a quick way to do this via `NamedTuple`.

Unfortunately, whereas method `lm` may seem to improve your results - it claims to find a solution with ~ 10 times less cost (30.7) than that from `trf` (399) - it's not usable because it doesn't respect your bounds. There is no magic bullet to improve the accuracy. Knowledge of the domain problem is necessary. If some equations "matter more" to the solution than others, you can simply scale those equations by their weights.

Add regression tests. For the results that I show, the equations are equivalent to your original equations.

Always check `result.success`.

A first pass can look like

```py
"""Ethanol and 1_Propanol with 3 trays"""

from pprint import pprint
from typing import NamedTuple

from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import numpy as np


class Vars(NamedTuple):
    e0_K_tr1_c2: float            # 0
    e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2: float       # 1
    e0_h_L_tr1: float             # 2
    e0_K_tr1_c1: float            # 3
    e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1: float       # 4
    e0_lambda_V_tr1: float        # 5
    e0_cp_V_tr1: float            # 6
    e0_f_int_tr1_c2: float        # 7
    e0_f_int_tr1_c1: float        # 8
    e0_x_L_tr1_c2: float          # 9
    e0_x_L_tr1_c1: float          # 10
    e0_cp_L_tr1: float            # 11
    e0_h_V_tr1: float             # 12
    e0_D_L_tr1: float             # 13
    e0_F_V_tr1: float             # 14
    e0_D_V_tr1: float             # 15
    e0_beta_L_tr1: float          # 16
    e0_e_int_tr1: float           # 17
    e0_alpha_L_tr1: float         # 18
    e0_rho_L_tr1: float           # 19
    e0_x_V_tr1_c2: float          # 20
    e0_lambda_L_tr1: float        # 21
    e0_x_V_tr1_c1: float          # 22
    e0_F_L_tr1: float             # 23
    e0_rho_V_tr1: float           # 24
    e0_beta_V_tr1: float          # 25
    e0_T_V_tr1: float             # 26
    e0_alpha_V_tr1: float         # 27
    e0_T_int_tr1: float           # 28
    e0_T_L_tr1: float             # 29
    e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2: float       # 30
    e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1: float       # 31


def equations(x: np.ndarray) -> tuple[float, ...]:
    v = Vars(*x)

    eq1 = v.e0_alpha_L_tr1 - v.e0_beta_L_tr1 * v.e0_rho_L_tr1 * v.e0_cp_L_tr1 * (
        v.e0_lambda_L_tr1 / (v.e0_rho_L_tr1 * v.e0_cp_L_tr1 * v.e0_D_L_tr1)
    ) ** (2 / 3)

    eq2 = v.e0_rho_L_tr1 - (732 * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1 + 747 * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2)
    eq3 = v.e0_D_L_tr1 - (1.25E-5 * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1 + 1.6E-6 * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2)

    eq4 = v.e0_h_L_tr1 - (
        (
            -6021.54
            + 0.055134232180918 * (v.e0_T_L_tr1 - 298)
            + 2.61275786690816
        ) * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1
        + (
            -6883.827
            + 0.058471271259418 * (v.e0_T_L_tr1 - 298)
            + 2.38446400137128
        ) * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2
    )

    eq5 = v.e0_cp_L_tr1 - (
        (
            0.055134232180918 * v.e0_T_L_tr1 + 2.61275786690816
        ) * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1
        + (
            0.058471271259418 * v.e0_T_L_tr1 + 2.38446400137128
        ) * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2
    )
    eq6 = v.e0_lambda_L_tr1 - (
        (
            0.001318 * v.e0_T_L_tr1 + 0.16762
        ) * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1
        + (
            -0.001075424413 * v.e0_T_L_tr1 + 0.155701011727667
        ) * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2
    )

    eq7 = v.e0_rho_V_tr1 - (1.746 * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1 + 2.76 * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2)
    eq8 = v.e0_D_V_tr1 - (1E-5 * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1 + 6.5E-6 * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2)

    eq9 = v.e0_h_V_tr1 - (
        (
            -6021.54
            + 0.015220202121093 * (v.e0_T_V_tr1 - 298)
            + 1.60395800121061
            + 922.194
        ) * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1
        + (
            -6883.827
            + 0.01847750929725 * (v.e0_T_V_tr1 - 298)
            + 1.43843773750579
            + 1067.523
        ) * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2
    )
    eq10 = v.e0_cp_V_tr1 - (
        (
            0.015220202121093 * v.e0_T_V_tr1 + 1.60395800121061
        ) * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1
        + (
            0.01847750929725 * v.e0_T_V_tr1 + 1.43843773750579
        ) * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2
    )
    eq11 = v.e0_lambda_V_tr1 - (
        (
            5.07392141746E-4 * v.e0_T_L_tr1 + 0.015070468544221
        ) * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1
        + (
            4.89248E-4 * v.e0_T_L_tr1 + 0.014354384
        ) * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2
    )

    eq12 = v.e0_K_tr1_c1 - 1 / 10**(5.24677 - 1598.673 / (v.e0_T_int_tr1 + 46.424))
    eq13 = v.e0_K_tr1_c2 - 1 / 10**(5.31384 - 1690.864 / (v.e0_T_int_tr1 + 51.804))

    eq14 = v.e0_alpha_V_tr1 - (
        v.e0_beta_V_tr1 * v.e0_rho_V_tr1 * v.e0_cp_V_tr1 * (
            v.e0_lambda_V_tr1 / (
                v.e0_rho_V_tr1 * v.e0_cp_V_tr1 * v.e0_D_V_tr1
            )
        ) ** (2 / 3)
    )

    eq15 = -(2 * 28000 - v.e0_F_L_tr1 * v.e0_h_L_tr1 + v.e0_e_int_tr1 * 0.002)
    eq16 = -(0.2 * 30000 - v.e0_F_V_tr1 * v.e0_h_V_tr1 - v.e0_e_int_tr1 * 0.002)
    eq17 = -(2 * 0.5 - v.e0_F_L_tr1 * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1 + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 * 0.002)
    eq18 = -(2 * 0.5 - v.e0_F_L_tr1 * v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2 + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2 * 0.002)
    eq19 = -(0.2 * 0.6 - v.e0_F_V_tr1 * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1 - v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 * 0.002)
    eq20 = -(0.2 * 0.4 - v.e0_F_V_tr1 * v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2 - v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2 * 0.002)

    eq21 = -(v.e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1 - v.e0_K_tr1_c1 * v.e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1)
    eq22 = -(v.e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2 - v.e0_K_tr1_c2 * v.e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2)

    eq23 = v.e0_e_int_tr1 - (
        v.e0_alpha_L_tr1 * (v.e0_T_int_tr1 - v.e0_T_L_tr1)
        + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 * (
            -6021.54
            + 0.055134232180918 * (v.e0_T_L_tr1 - 298)
            + 2.61275786690816
            # really?
        # )
            + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2 * (
                -6883.827 +
                0.058471271259418 * (v.e0_T_L_tr1 - 298)
                + 2.38446400137128
            )
        )
    )

    eq24 = v.e0_e_int_tr1 - (
        v.e0_alpha_V_tr1 * (v.e0_T_V_tr1 - v.e0_T_int_tr1)
        + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 * (
            -6021.54
            + 0.015220202121093 * (v.e0_T_V_tr1 - 298)
            + 1.60395800121061
            + 922.194
            # really?
        # )
            + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2 * (
                -6883.827
                + 0.01847750929725 * (v.e0_T_V_tr1 - 298)
                + 1.43843773750579
                + 1067.523
            )
        )
    )

    eq25 = v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 - (
        v.e0_rho_L_tr1 * v.e0_beta_L_tr1 * (
            v.e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1 - v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1
        )
        + v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1 * (v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2)
    )
    eq26 = v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2 - (
        v.e0_rho_L_tr1 * v.e0_beta_L_tr1 * (
            v.e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2 - v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2
        )
        + v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2 * (v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2)
    )
    eq27 = v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 - (
        v.e0_rho_V_tr1 * v.e0_beta_V_tr1 * (
            v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1 - v.e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1
        )
        + v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1 * (v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2)
    )
    eq28 = v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2 - (
        v.e0_rho_V_tr1 * v.e0_beta_V_tr1 * (
            v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2 - v.e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2
        )
        + v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2 * (v.e0_f_int_tr1_c1 + v.e0_f_int_tr1_c2)
    )

    eq29 = 1 - (v.e0_x_L_tr1_c1 + v.e0_x_L_tr1_c2)
    eq30 = 1 - (v.e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1 + v.e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2)
    eq31 = 1 - (v.e0_x_V_tr1_c1 + v.e0_x_V_tr1_c2)
    eq32 = 1 - (v.e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1 + v.e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2)

    return (eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10,
            eq11, eq12, eq13, eq14, eq15, eq16, eq17, eq18, eq19, eq20,
            eq21, eq22, eq23, eq24, eq25, eq26, eq27, eq28, eq29, eq30,
            eq31, eq32)


def regression_test(x0: np.ndarray) -> None:
    y = equations(x0)
    assert np.allclose(
        y,
        [ 0.00000000e+00, -7.38500000e+02,  9.99992950e-01,  6.44709509e+03,
         -2.25156291e+01,  7.93463011e-01, -1.25300000e+00,  9.99991750e-01,
          5.45609068e+03, -6.75527448e+00,  8.00909148e-01,  9.60890608e-01,
          9.50476815e-01,  0.00000000e+00, -5.59990020e+04, -5.99899800e+03,
         -5.02000000e-01, -5.02000000e-01,  3.82000000e-01,  4.22000000e-01,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.28931902e+04,  1.09111814e+04,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
          ],
        rtol=0, atol=1e-4,
    )

    rand = default_rng(seed=0)
    x = rand.uniform(low=0, high=2, size=32)
    y = equations(x)
    assert np.allclose(
        y,
        [-8.89664807e-02, -2.59056243e+03,  6.71477620e-02,  2.27496385e+04,
         -8.97636119e+00, -3.16304973e-01, -1.26737482e+00,  3.51297461e-01,
          7.17475798e+03, -1.06230892e+00,  1.80356351e+00, -1.59115277e+28,
         -3.04937193e+26, -6.69625188e-01, -5.59998961e+04, -5.99749540e+03,
          1.10987295e+00,  1.41775827e+00,  1.83947353e+00,  5.57239541e-03,
         -7.24077112e-01, -6.89518259e-01,  1.75063897e+04,  1.47800191e+04,
         -3.05993271e+00, -1.36098936e+00, -2.85999752e+00,  2.56167351e+00,
         -2.50185196e+00, -1.16611391e+00, -3.97888172e-01, -1.15473631e+00,
         ],
        rtol=1e-8, atol=0,
    )


def make_x0() -> np.ndarray:
    x0 = np.ones(32)
    x0[[1,4,9,10,20,22,30,31]] = 0.5
    x0[[26,28,29]] = 370
    return x0


def solve(x0: np.ndarray) -> Vars:
    upper_bounds = np.full(shape=32, fill_value=np.inf)
    upper_bounds[[1,4,9,10,20,22,30,31]] = 1

    bottom_bounds = np.zeros(32)
    bottom_bounds[[26,28,29]] = 340

    res = least_squares(
        fun=equations, x0=x0,
        bounds=(bottom_bounds, upper_bounds),  # not supported in lm
        method='trf',
        ftol=1e-10, xtol=1e-10, gtol=1e-10,
    )
    assert res.success
    return Vars(*res.x)


def dump(x: Vars) -> None:
    pprint(x._asdict())


def main() -> None:
    x0 = make_x0()
    regression_test(x0)
    x = solve(x0)
    dump(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
{'e0_D_L_tr1': 0.9984442691049119,
 'e0_D_V_tr1': 0.9986041251126907,
 'e0_F_L_tr1': 128.59184097299763,
 'e0_F_V_tr1': 194.05957359631154,
 'e0_K_tr1_c1': 0.9994676910341592,
 'e0_K_tr1_c2': 0.999729237718534,
 'e0_T_L_tr1': 340.0,
 'e0_T_V_tr1': 559.936902192616,
 'e0_T_int_tr1': 369.2496832286959,
 'e0_alpha_L_tr1': 7.5810026415896,
 'e0_alpha_V_tr1': 30.124493018891847,
 'e0_beta_L_tr1': 0.0,
 'e0_beta_V_tr1': 1.2479650000565898,
 'e0_cp_L_tr1': 5.468269302698259,
 'e0_cp_V_tr1': 1.0196495285046383,
 'e0_e_int_tr1': 1856.5186325404206,
 'e0_f_int_tr1_c1': 0.11670635205679133,
 'e0_f_int_tr1_c2': 0.39727951871442857,
 'e0_h_L_tr1': 190.08447743399068,
 'e0_h_V_tr1': 22.650731758245296,
 'e0_lambda_L_tr1': 1.0083185179925418,
 'e0_lambda_V_tr1': 1.0368032854477796,
 'e0_rho_L_tr1': 1.0430730156966466,
 'e0_rho_V_tr1': 0.9986707757704435,
 'e0_x_L_tr1_c1': 0.0,
 'e0_x_L_tr1_c2': 0.0,
 'e0_x_Lint_tr1_c1': 0.5001045740608061,
 'e0_x_Lint_tr1_c2': 0.49992448934879186,
 'e0_x_V_tr1_c1': 1.4663484981775705e-16,
 'e0_x_V_tr1_c2': 0.00041819098423356144,
 'e0_x_Vint_tr1_c1': 0.4998465855173379,
 'e0_x_Vint_tr1_c2': 0.4995202978525341}
```